# Jquery show div after form post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a link on a page that toggles the visibility of a div. The div contains filter options for a form, which is posted. I would like to retain the filter visibility after a post; so if its open before post, it remains open after post.

Here is my script code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // choose text for the show/hide link
    var showText="Show Filter Options";
    var hideText="Hide Filter Options";

    // create the toggle link
    $("#filter-params").before("<p><a href='#' id='toggle-link'>"+showText+"</a>");

    // hide the content
    $('#filter-params').hide();

    // capture clicks on the newly created link
    $('a#toggle-link').click(function() {

        // change the link text
        if ($('a#toggle-link').text()==showText) {
            $('a#toggle-link').text(hideText);
        }
        else {
            $('a#toggle-link').text(showText);
        }

        // toggle the display
        $('#filter-params').toggle('slow');

        // return false so any link destination is not followed
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: After the form is posted, do you come back to the same page ?

Comment: Is this the whole script? Posting happens normally, not via AJAX? If so, why the jQuery approach?

Comment: You could either do this by checking on some post variables in your php script or by creating a session variable that keeps track of whether the div was open or closed last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you store a boolean value in a hidden field that is posted along with the form? This way in PHP you'll know its value and you can render it correctly in your next response.

<strike>Let me know if you need an example.</strike>

```
<?php
    var $defaultFilterSetting = false;

    // This code only runs when you've performed a post back to this page
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {
        $defaultFilterSetting = $_POST["defaultFilterSetting"];
    }
?>

<form name="input" action="<?php $PHP_SELF;?>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="defaultFilterSetting" value="<?=$defaultFilterSetting?>" />
    <!-- ... all other html elements -->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var filterSetting = $('input[name="defaultFilterSetting"]').val();
    alert(filterSetting);
    // you can change the value here and it will be posted back everytime
    // eg. let's change it to true here:
    $('input[name="defaultFilterSetting"]').val(true);
    // if you would do another postback it should alert true now;
</script>
```

Forgive me if it contains typos, it's been a while since I've written PHP and I don't have a host setup to test it against. So this is written by heart.

Comment: Would be great to see an example.

Answer (score 1):

Store its state in a cookie.

The [jQuery Cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) abstracts away some of the annoying things about setting and reading cookies in JavaScript.

Comment: It's a little bit overkill to store something stupid as this in a cookie don't you think? I agree it's easier, but it doesn't work at all when you don't have cookies enabled.

Comment: @Peter Where would you suggest you store it? It seems like a non critical thing, so no cookies wouldn't be the end of the world.

Comment: Since we're dealing with the POST of a form I think it's best to send this value along with that POST and let php set the initial value for the response that follows.

Answer (score 0):

You can include php inside your script tag.

For example in what I did today I have in my

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'] 
{
    $stall_type = sanitize($_POST['stall_type']; 
}
```

and then in my script tag (document.ready) further down the same page I have

```
$('.tandem').hide();

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if ($stall_type == 'tandem')
    { ?>
        $('.tandem').show();
    <?php } else { ?>
        $('.tandem').hide();
    <?php }             
} ?>
```