# Best method to call AJAX script

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I need to call some Javascript that grabs data from the Twitter API on script load and then sends the data to POST. It is not attached to a UI and the action is automatic on script load.

What is the best way to approach this? Do I call a view with the AJAX script in it or is there a better, more conventional way to handle this in codeigniter? Links and examples welcome.

From what I know, business logic isn't supposed to be in the `view`. All the script does is process data. So where do I put this AJAX script?

Comment: What javascript file? I though to perform an API call, you doesnt need to use any javascript file.

Comment: Your right, I don't (need) JS but I want to use JS instead of putting the load on my server to call the API. In any case, the question isn't really about twitter.

Comment: @Marek, I'm not calling the JS file with AJAX, I rephrased my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing it on the client side, even if it's just data processing (how you are processing data on the client btw?), the HTML/javascript I'd say belongs in a view.  Also, are you sure you want your twitter API creds out there for everyone to see?  If someone hijacks that it could break your app when they start overloading the API user account and lock it out by doing too many requests.

Comment: The only thing im processing client side is the call to the twitter API. The API call is public and doesn't require authentication, it's just rate limited so I'm forwarding the request client side. I send the data to POST , and then I need to re-direct the user to another page based on the data. I need some help with this last part actually too because I'm not sure how to call another view and put new data in it after the POST. If that makes any sense :)

Comment: @Ilya Berelson well, it sounds a bit complicated, but basically you'd setup another view which would be a div that gets its content via an ajax call, and trigger that to load the data after the post data part has returned true.

Comment: .@profitphp this sounds perfect. Do you think you can edit your post with an example? Your the first person to understand what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @Ilya Berelson That'd be a bit of work. Basically.. i'd return a javascript after the _POST processing part is done, and that javascript will be loaded into the client page which will then call the method to update the div with data from the database. Are you using jquery at all? that'd make life easier.

Comment: Ok, I'll play around with this. I think I understand what your saying. Takes me a mile further then where I was. Thanks.

Comment: .@profitphp is this what your referring to? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260678/jquery-show-div-after-form-post

Comment: @Ilya Berelson ya thats pretty close.